# Diverging/Converging edge using svg filter (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to make my force-directed graph using d3.js somewhat more dynamic. One goal for this is to have the edges converge/diverge, based on some datum from the source and target node.

Illustration:
[image]

Using svg filters and more specifically [feMorpohology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feMorphology), I am able to dilute or erode the edges. Although this seems close, I can't seem to find how to make the edges converge/diverge (e.g. start on width 10, end at width 5 or vice versa).

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "make the edges converge/diverge" ?  I don't follow.

Comment: I think you have nothing to do with `feMorpohology` here. Just replace lines with closed paths and get the effect you need.

Comment: My apologies for the late answer;

With converging for example, I mean that the path between two nodes starts at it's source node with a width of, say, 5px, and it ends at it's target node at a width of , say, 2px. Vice versa for diverging. The edge then gets a sort of trapezoid-shape.

I feel that closed paths are indeed the way to go. However, how do I set the paths for each link separately?